# Trying to build a simple Live Chart into my WPF application (ColumnSeries)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, livecharts

I have been trying to build a Live Chart into my WPF application for a few days.

I want a simple diagram.
Column Series, that should show int values as bars and below the timestamp.

I build it with MVVM and tried to find a solution with this tutorial. https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basic%20Column

My XAML code:

`<lvc:CartesianChart> 
    <lvc:CartesianChart.Series> 
        <lvc:ColumnSeries Values="{Binding RawDataSeries, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> 
    </lvc:CartesianChart.Series> 
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX > 
        <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding Labels}"> 
            <lvc:Axis.Separator> 
                <lvc:Separator Step="1"></lvc:Separator> 
            </lvc:Axis.Separator> 
        </lvc:Axis> 
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX> 
</lvc:CartesianChart>`

My test code in the viewmodel:

```
public void SetChart(int value)
{
var customerVmMapper = Mappers.Weighted<DateTimePoint>().X((x, index) => index).Y(x => x.Value);

Charting.For<DateTimePoint>(customerVmMapper);

            var list = new List<DateTimePoint>()
            {
                new DateTimePoint() {Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Value = value},
                new DateTimePoint() {Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Value = 78},
                new DateTimePoint() {Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Value = 21}
            };

            var values = new ChartValues<DateTimePoint>();
            foreach (var obj in list)
            {
                values.Add(obj);
            }

            RawDataSeries = values;
        }

        public ChartValues<DateTimePoint> RawDataSeries
        {
            get => _rawDataSeries;
            set
            {
                _rawDataSeries = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public class DateTimePoint
        {
            public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
            public int Value { get; set; }
        }
```

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the correct x/y mapping of the data object, the interval of the x-axis
and a label formatter to print the timestamps:

**ChartModel.cs**

```
public class ChartModel
{
  public ChartModel()
  {
    CartesianMapper<DateTimePoint> mapper = Mappers.Xy<DateTimePoint>()
      .X((item) => (double) item.Timestamp.Ticks / TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).Ticks) // Set interval to 5 minutes
      .Y(item => item.Value)
      .Fill((item) => item.Value > 99 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Blue);

    var series = new ColumnSeries()
    {
      Title = "Timestamp Values",
      Configuration = mapper,
      Values = new ChartValues<DateTimePoint>
      {
        new DateTimePoint() {Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Value = 100},
        new DateTimePoint() {Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), Value = 78},
        new DateTimePoint() {Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), Value = 21}
      }
    };
    this.SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection() { series };
  }

  public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }

  public Func<double, string> LabelFormatter =>
    value => new DateTime((long) value * TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).Ticks).ToString("t");
}
```

**DateTimePoint.cs**

```
public class DateTimePoint
{
  public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<CartesianChart Margin="20"
                Height="300"
                Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}"
                LegendLocation="Left">
  <CartesianChart.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ChartModel />
  </CartesianChart.DataContext>

  <CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <Axis Title="Timestamp"
          LabelFormatter="{Binding LabelFormatter}">
    </Axis>
  </CartesianChart.AxisX>
</CartesianChart>
```

Also read the [Live Charts: Date Time](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Date%20Time) example.